# Mutation operator for genetic algorithms for solving traveling salesman problem

Tags: genetic-algorithms, graph-traversal

I need help help for defining mutation operator for traveling salesman problem.

I'm currently using this now (pseudocode):

```
mutate ( strand ):
    for n in random_interval ( min_gene_index, max_gene_index ):
        i := random_interval ( min_gene_index, max_gene_index );
        j := random_interval ( min_gene_index, max_gene_index );
        swap ( strand[i], strand[j] );
```

So when swapping is executed two cities in the route is swapped.
The goal is that it needs to be fast and effective. I don't want it to be a performance hit in the main loop. Can I improve my implementation or is there any other alternative that is better?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Many different mutation (and crossover) operators have been devised for the TSP and each give different results.

You could use domain specific information (heuristic mutation).

E.g. the [2-opt mutation](http://www.cs.indiana.edu/cgi-bin/techreports/TRNNN.cgi?trnum=TR314) is an often used algorithm.

It usually improves solutions compared to a crossover-only approach (in ([2](http://www.complex-systems.com/pdf/06-6-5.pdf)) the 2-opt mutation operator was tested even without crossover with good results).

```
      ..                   ..
     /  \                 /  \
    /    \               /    \
  (a)    (c)           (a)    (c)
     \  /               |      |
      \/         =>     |      |
      /\                |      |
     /  \               |      |
  (d)    (b)           (d)    (b)
    \    /               \    /
     \  /                 \  /
      ..                   ..
```

The operator randomly select two edges e.g. `(a,b)` and `(c,d)` from the tour and check if:

```
distance(a, b) + distance (c, d) > distance(a, d) + distance(c, b)
```

if this is the case the tour is changed by removing `(a,b)` and `(c,d)` and replacing them with the edges `(a,d)` and `(c,b)`.

This is quite lightweight and simple to implement.

**References**

1. [Parallel Genetic Algorithms Applied to the Traveling Salesman Problem](http://www.cs.indiana.edu/cgi-bin/techreports/TRNNN.cgi?trnum=TR314)
2. [Schema analysis of the traveling salesman problem using genetic algorithms](http://www.complex-systems.com/pdf/06-6-5.pdf)

Answer (score 0):

Unless you're doing some really nonstandard version of the TSP, I don't think you need a loop here. With a GA using a binary encoding of real-valued parameters, occasionally you might need a loop like

```
for each gene:
    for each bit in the gene:
        do something
```

It's fairly rare even then, but occasionally you do want to observe parameter boundaries like that.

For TSP though, the canonical representation is just a permutation of integers representing the cities in the order they occur in the tour. If you want to make one swap (the smallest valid mutation), then you just do

```
def mutate(candidate):
    p1 = random_index()
    p2 = random_index()
    swap(candidate[p1], candidate[p2])
```

You can try doing the swap trick with bitwise operators, but I don't imagine it would make a noticeable difference. Otherwise, this is about as efficient as you can get.